# How to add organization chart on page

Tags: organization-browser

How to show the organization chart (organization browser) on a regular SharePoint page? Would it be possible to set it start from a specific user account?

The organization chart in My Sites uses SilverLight and is based on the hierarchy of manager user profile properties.
This seems to work better in O365 but shows nothing on-premises.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For your requirement you can make use of Organization Browser web part.

The OOTB feature of the Organization Browser relies on the manager fields in the Active Directory, so the hierarchy is built on it. People in the same team will share the same manager. The collegues will be shown on the same level (in the horizontal row) and you'll see people you report to (or your manager reports to) on the vertical column. You will also see in the same column people "under" you.

Have a look at the below links to configure it.

1. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/22557919-5a26-4927-b962-4aa48ed78d0b/organization-browser-webpart?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious
2. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/45f177c4-c159-4b43-9899-2468184efb98/organization-browser-web-part-to-show-whole-organization?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious
3. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/d31d080f-3f13-4c5b-8ae5-68cb4418d7c0/organization-browser-web-part?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

Or You can create your own Organization webpart using the following links,

1. [How to create an organizational chart with SharePoint and Office 2013](http://en.share-gate.com/blog/create-organizational-chart-sharepoint-office-2013)
2. [Org Chart in SharePoint 2010 using Google API](http://orgchartgoogleapi.codeplex.com/)
3. [Silverlight Organization Chart.](http://silverorgchart.codeplex.com/discussions)

Answer (score 3):

Solved by adding the below content to a CEWP on the page with organization browser:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function CreateHierarchyChartControl(parentId, profileId, type, persistControlId) {
  var i = profileId.indexOf("|");
  var claimsmode = profileId.substr(i-1,1);
  if((i >=0 ) & (claimsmode=="w"))
  {
   profileId = profileId.substr(i+1,profileId.length-i-1);
   var initParam = profileId + ',' + type + ',' + persistControlId;
   var host = document.getElementById(parentId);
   host.setAttribute('width', '100%');
   host.setAttribute('height', '100%');
   Silverlight.createObject('/_layouts/ClientBin/hierarchychart.xap',
    host,
    'ProfileBrowserSilverlightControl',
    {
     top: '30',
     width: '100%',
     height: '100%',
     version: '2.0',
     isWindowless: 'true',
     enableHtmlAccess: 'true'
    },
    {
     onLoad: OnHierarchyChartLoaded
    },
     initParam,
     null);
    }
  }
</script>`
```

where profileId (DOMAIN\user) sets the top-level profile for the organization browser (which is on the same page).

Reference:

- solution from here: http://www.sptechlearn.com/2013/05/using-sharepoint-2013-organization.html
- older discussions: http://blog.karstein-consulting.com/2011/06/16/problem-and-workaround-organization-browser-silverlight-web-part-is-empty-on-other-site-than-mysite/