# How do I setup a Sharepoint Org Chart that automatically sync with AD?

Tags: web-part, active-directory, organization-browser

Is there a way to do this out of box?  And if not, does someone recommend a webpart that I can install?

Thanks!

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/84644/how-to-add-organization-chart-on-page

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint includes an OrgChart webpart and it's enabled in user profile pages by default.  You however have to have user profile service configured correctly and in Active Directory the manager property has to be set.

If you are using SharePoint online or 2013 with apps enabled you may be able to use one the apps available from the store:
https://store.office.com/search.aspx?productgroup=SharePoint&qu=Org%20chart

If you are on 2010 (or 2013 wihtout apps) there is a "market place" perse, but you browse the web and find other vendors that offer products like this:  https://sharepointorgchart.com/

Most people find the included Org chart functional enough for their needs - so I would encourage you to check that out. In 2013 it's called the "organization browser" web part.

Comment: We are on SharePoint 2010.

Comment: 2010 doesn't have apps but you still have a built in Org Chart web part, and there are still 3rd party options you can deploy.